# List not being populated from other view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller where the user can populate an item. Upon exiting the view that object should be saved, and loaded by the previous view which contains a list of all these objects. My NSLog shows that the object is being saved, but I can't get it to appear in the list view.

Code for both controllers is below. Thanks

List Controller

```
#import "ItemsViewController.h"
#import "Calculation.h"
#import "CalculationItemStore.h"
#import "CalculationDetailViewController.h"

@interface ItemsViewController()
@property UISegmentedControl *segment;

@end

@implementation ItemsViewController

- (instancetype)init
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {

        UINavigationItem *navItem = self.navigationItem;
        navItem.title = @"MACS";

        // Create a new bar button item that will send
        // addNewItem: to CalculationsViewController
        UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(addNewItem:)];


        // Set this bar button item as the right item in the navigationItem
        navItem.rightBarButtonItem = bbi;

        navItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Publication", @"About", nil]];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _segment;
    [_segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[CalculationItemStore sharedStore] allCalculations] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get a new or recycled cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Set the text on the cell with the description of the item
    // that is at the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
    // will appear in on the tableview
    NSArray *items = [[CalculationItemStore sharedStore] allCalculations];
    Calculation *item = items[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = item.title;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CalculationDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[CalculationDetailViewController alloc] init];

    NSArray *items = [[CalculationItemStore sharedStore] allCalculations];
    Calculation *selectedItem = items[indexPath.row];

    // Give detail view controller a pointer to the item object in row
    detailViewController.calculation = selectedItem;

    // Push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController
                                         animated:YES];
}

- (void)   tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // If the table view is asking to commit a delete command...
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSArray *items = [[CalculationItemStore sharedStore] allCalculations];
        Calculation *item = items[indexPath.row];
        [[CalculationItemStore sharedStore] removeItem:item];

        // Also remove that row from the table view with an animation
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)   tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    [[CalculationItemStore sharedStore] moveItemAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row
                                        toIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}

- (void)segmentPressed:(id)sender {

    if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex ==0) {

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ferm.forestry.oregonstate.edu/facstaff/leshchinsky-ben"]];

    }else if(_segment.selectedSegmentIndex ==1){

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MACSLoad@2x.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview: imageView];
        sleep(5);
        imageView.hidden = YES;

    }


}

- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender
{
    // Create a new Calculation and add it to the store
    Calculation *newItem = [[CalculationItemStore sharedStore] createCalculation];

    CalculationDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[CalculationDetailViewController alloc]initForNewItem:YES];
    detailViewController.calculation = newItem;

    detailViewController.dismissBlock = ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    };

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
  //  [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Item controller save method

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //clear responder
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    //save changes
    BOOL success = [[CalculationItemStore sharedStore]saveChanges];
    if(success){
        NSLog(@"Saved all calcs");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"failure saving");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the order of `viewWillAppear:` in List Controller and `viewWillDisappear:` in Item Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that by the time the table reloadData is called on the first controller, the second one is not done loading. You could notify the first VC to reload the data once the second one is done saving It can be notified using

1. create a delegate on the second one or
2. using notifications

Let me know if you need more details on how to do this!

Looks like there is also an issue with the object creation. 
your calculation elements are not getting created properly. When you are ready to save.. look at the contents of self.privateItems. They values filled in are nil. You will need to instantiate the  Strings properly.

engineerName needs to be alloc'd and other strings as well.
and when user hits Done, the values from the text boxes need to be set to the your data model.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm actually passing it back correctly to be honest. If you wouldn't mind taking a look, this is a link to the controller on github. https://github.com/Brabon/Mobile-Anchor-Capacity-System/blob/master/Mobile%20Anchor%20Capacity%20System/CalculationDetailViewController.m

Comment: updated answer take a look. Yes data is not being stored correctly